# Inserindo um input de texto com um botão em PHP

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, input, text

Sou iniciante em PHP e gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de acrescentar um input text no PHP utilizando um botão. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação php para controle de almoxarifado e desejo criar uma rotina de recebimento de mercadoria denominada 'carregamento'. Então 'carregamento' seria constituída de um Número de carregamento e os produtos nele contidos. Porém como é desconhecido o números de produtos diferentes que um carregamento pode ter, preciso ter como acrescentar novas entradas no form de acordo com a necessidade do usuário. Isso é possível?

Comment: PHP não tem botão nem input text. Isso é coisa de HTML, e para mudar dinamicamente no cliente precisa de JS. Note que o PHP simplesmente processa dados e monta a página do lado do servidor. Mesmo que ele gere um HTML, isso sempre acontece antes do cliente receber os dados e interagir com a página. Para mudar isso do lado do cliente, ou usa JS/Ajax e similares, ou recarrega a página/iframe (prefira o JS/Ajax, a não ser que precise lidar com sistemas bem primitivos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite, de acordo meu entendimento, sua dúvida pode ser resolvida com JavaScript, mais precisamente o jQuery..

Se em PHP, você desejar que o PHP escreva o formulário, faça mais ou menos assim usando estrutura de repetição **for()**:

**form.php**

```
<?php
```

$numCampos = $_GET["num_campos"];

echo '<form method="POST">
<!-- Dados repetidos --!>
';

for($i = 0; $i < $numCampos; $i++) {
    echo '<label for="amox_'.$i.'">Amox '.($i+1).'</label> <input type="text" name="amox[]" id="amox_'.$i.'"><br />
';
}

echo '</form>';

?>

E no navegador você acessa: *http://localhost/form.php?num_campos=4*

E ele irá retornar:

```
<form method="POST">
<!-- Dados repetidos -->
<label for="amox_0">Amox 1</label> <input name="amox[]" id="amox_0" type="text"><br>
<label for="amox_1">Amox 2</label> <input name="amox[]" id="amox_1" type="text"><br>
<label for="amox_2">Amox 3</label> <input name="amox[]" id="amox_2" type="text"><br>
<label for="amox_3">Amox 4</label> <input name="amox[]" id="amox_3" type="text"><br>
</form>
```

Ou você pode fazer em jQuery que ficará muito mais dinâmico e visualmente bonito para o usuário, usando **jQuery.append()**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso mesmo que eu estava querendo, embora a solução do amigo acima tb resolveria, porém, por ter ainda pouco conhecimento de CSS e JAVASCRIPT vou considerar a sua resposta pro meu problema. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * { font-family:Arial; }
        h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
        h2 a { color: #224f99; }
        a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
        a:hover { color:#802727; }
        p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

        input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
                var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
                var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

                $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">X</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                    i++;
                    return false;
                });

                $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                    if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Adicionar campo</a></h2>

        <div id="p_scents">
            <p>
                <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="" /></label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```